# Is it any way to implement a linked list with indexed access too?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, indexing, linked-list

I'm in the need of sort of a linked list structure, but if it had indexed access too it would be great.

Is it any way to accomplish that?

EDIT: I'm writing in C, but it may be for any language.

Comment: All sorts of platforms have this, e.g. java's `java.util.Linkedlist`. Go look it up.

Comment: I assume he means that indexing needs to be fairly fast.  `java.util.LinkedList` has O(n) indexing.

Comment: Do you mean that the indexes change with each add/remove, right?

Comment: Loads of people have posted for this guy and he doesn't have the courtesy to accept answers.

Answer (score 3):

One method of achieving your goal is to implement a random or deterministic [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). On the bottom level - you have your linked list with your items.

In order to get to elements using indexes, you'll need to add information to the inner nodes - of how many nodes are in the low most level, from this node until the next node on this level. This information can be added and maintained in O(logn).

This solution complexity is:
Add, Remove, Go to index, all work in O(logn).

The down side of this solution is that it is much more difficult to implement than the regular linked list. So using a regular linked list, you get Add, Remove in O(1), and Go to index in O(n).

Comment: Harder to implement than a plain linked list, but easier than a balanced tree of linked nodes. Gets my vote.

Comment: +1. I wasn't sure how to get skiplists to index properly.  However it occurs to me now that skiplists are just a form of automagically balanced tree, so you can use the same basic node-count structures.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a tree for what you are aiming at.  Make a binary tree that maintains the weights of each node of the tree (where the weight is equal to the number of nodes attached to that node, including itself).  If you have a balancing scheme available for the tree, then insertions are still O(log n), since you only need to add one to the ancestor nodes' weights.  Getting a node by index is O(log n), since you need only look at the indices of the ancestors of your desired node and the two children of each of those ancestors.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer. 
One problem I see with it, is that the data structure is ordered according to something that is not clear (aka "insert after this node"). It remains to figure out how to balance a tree so that this property remains. It shouldn't be too hard (with 2-3 trees for example), but it does differ from regular balanced trees in which keys dictate what is located where.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely a problem.  I would imagine that you'd keep the actual data at the bottom in a linked list of their own, and all the interior nodes of the tree would only contain the weights.  One algorithm for this that I learned of in grad school is to leave the tree (and any subtree) alone until one side is N times the weight of the other.  If this property holds true for any subtree after an insertion or deletion, reconstruct the tree for the highest such subtree.  This maintains O(log n) time on average.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving array like indexing in languages like C++, Java, Python, one would have to overload the array indexing operator [] for a class which implements the linked list data structure. The implementation would be O(n). In C since operator overloading is not possible, hence one would have to write a function which takes the linked list data structure and a position and returns the corresponding object.

In case a faster order access is required, one would have to use a different data structure like the BTree suggested by jprete or a dynamic array (which automatically grows as and when new elements are added to it). A quick example would be `std::vector` in C++ standard library.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server row items in the [clustered index are arranged like so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443.aspx):

```
   .
 /  \   
/\  /\  
*-*-*-*
```

The linked list is in the leaves `(*-*-*)`. The linked list is ordered allowing fast directional scanning, and the tree serves as a `road-map' into the linked-list. So you would need a key-value pair for your items and then a data structure that encapsulates the tree and linked list.

so your data structure might look something like this:

```
struct ll_node
{
     kv_pair current;
     ll_node * next;
};

struct tree_node
{
   value_type value;
   short isLeaf;        

   union
   {
      tree_node * left_child;
      kv_pair * left_leaf;
   }
   union
   {
      tree_node * right_child;
      kv_pair * right_leaf
   }
};

struct indexed_ll
{
    tree_node * tree_root;
    ll_node * linked_list_tail;
};
```